# Use the overloading mechanism instead of the optional parameters

Tags: c#, sonarqube, overloading

Right now sonar qube analysis shows an error in the build as follows,

and current code is

```
public ActionResult Strings(CultureInfo id = null)
 {
   CultureInfo cultureInfo = id ?? CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

}
```

so how should i modify?

Comment: This rule is mainly intended for multi-language compatibility (as some languages don't have this notion of optional parameters). If you look at recent releases you will see that this rule is no longer part of the SonarWay profile (the recommended quality profile). So except if this is of any concern for you otherwise I would recommend to turn off this rule.

Comment: My personal opinion is that this rule is useful only for libraries (e.g. nugets), because the default value is actually a constant and the compiler puts that constant into the calling method. If you change the default value, but don't recompile the caller, the default value will remain the same and the behavior could be unexpected. The same applies for the rule that does not allow having public constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess SonarQube wants you to define two actions:

```
ActionResult Strings(CultureInfo id);

ActionResult Strings();
```

with

```
public ActionResult Strings() {
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    return Strings(cultureInfo);
}
```

and `ActionResult Strings(CultureInfo id)` as before, but without the null check for `CultureInfo`.

Comment: is not that duplciating the code? if we are doing for 100 methods

Comment: Code duplication should be minimal if the new overrides still call the original method. But you can also configure SonarQube to ignore this issue. Or mark these issues as "Wont fix" by hand.